# How can i install Mongodb-odm-bundle with Symfony 5.1?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony5

Here are the errors that I get when i type :

```
composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.1.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.1.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.6 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 2.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.2.0 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1.0, 2.1.1].
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ^4.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.2.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Read the error message. You haven't installed the mongodb extension onto PHP. Composer can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need install extension mongodb. If you using ubuntu you can try command below:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mongodb
```

Hope it's help you.

Comment: Thanks for your return. I want to use `composer` to add in my composer.json.

PS:  My OS is MacOS.